# What is a Veteran Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, history, word-property

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Veteran Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

[image: Veteran words]

Here is a CSV version:

```
Veteran WordsTM, Not Veteran WordsTM

AGENT, ASSISTANT*
ALPHABET, FUNDAMENTALS
BUDGET, ALLOCATION*
JEANS, TROUSERS
LASER, BEAM
PAUSE, HALT*
RADIO, RECEIVER
SAUCE, FLAVOURING
TAXI, CARRIAGE
VETERAN**, WISE

*Half a Veteran WordTM
**Only just a Veteran WordTM
```

Comment: I made it blue for uniqueness

Comment: RECEIVER or RECEIEVER?

Comment: @randal'thor, typo it should be receiver but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: "CSV" means "comma-separated value", and is a [recognized, standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) for information. It's not just a plaintext version of a table. Please don't call things CSV unless they're really CSV.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As suggested by the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag, I think a Veteran Word™ may be

> something to do with foreign languages: specifically, **a word which is the same in English, French, and German**.

All the words in the left-hand column, according to

> my knowledge of French, supported by Google Translate for the rarer words and the German,

satisfy this criterion. VETERAN is "only just" a Veteran Word™ because

> the French for "veteran" is "vétéran", which is only the same word if we ignore diacritics.

The words in the right-hand column which are "half a Veteran Word™" are so because

> the English word is the same in *one* of French and German but not both: the German for "halt" is "Halt" but the French is "halte"; the French for "assistant" is "assistant" but the German is "Assistent"; the French for "allocation" is "allocation" but the German is "Zuweisung".

They're called Veteran Words™ because

> They are 'war veterans' as the 3 countries all fought in [WWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participants_in_World_War_I) and [WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_by_country)

Comment: Close! So close! But think about (war) veteran. Its not just french....

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32244832#32244832 - fix it!

Comment: Yay you got it!

Comment: @Mithrandir I realised that before seeing it in chat! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor, britain germany and france where the main countries. [And russia wouldn't work](https://translate.google.co.uk/#en/ru/veteran) :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil If we include a translation table, it might work.